# Is there a way to make a new PDF from existing PDF by extracting certain pages

Tags: pdf-format, windows

With the new "PDF" import and export features, is there a way to extract certain pages from a PDF and then export them as a new PDF document?

I tried the following:

```
Export["D:\\test.pdf",Import["D:\\source.pdf",{"PageGraphics",Range[1,10]}]]
```

But this doesn't break the documents into pages (it comes out as a single page). Also, it rasterizes the content. The original document had OCR.

Is there a way to programmatically create subpdfs from the existing giant one using Wolfram language?

It doesn't have to be the Import/Export mechanism. If someone knows some API that WL can access to achieve the result that would be helpful as well.

Comment: [pdftk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf#) ? There are many other methods shown on the same page.

Comment: I am using the free "PDFSam" for this.